# Jquery validate not working return valid result

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, jquery-validate

I have a html like,

```
<form id="create_campaign_form">
   <input type="text" name="campaign_name" id="campaign_name" >
</form>
<button id="validate_now" type="button" >OK</button>
```

And i have a  jquery with validate.js like,

```
  $.fn.validate_campaign=function(options){
  $("#create_campaign_form").validate({
        rules: {
            campaign_name  : "required",
           },
        messages:{      
            campaign_name   : "Please enter Campaign name",             
              },
 submitHandler: function(form) {
            alert(1);
            return true;
        }
    });
       $('#validate_now').click(function(){
          alert($('#create_campaign_form').valid());
       });
    }

     $(document).ready(function(){
         $(this).validate_campaign(); //Invoke on document ready

      });
```

my problem is ,when i enter value in textbox and click the buttin   `alert($('#create_campaign_form').valid());` alwaise return `false` and does not enter `submitHandler`

Comment: looks fine http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/L222J/2/

Comment: @ArunPJohny But it does not enter submitHandler(),I am using Query Validation Plugin - v1.11.1

Comment: it is because you are not submitting the form

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/L222J/4/

Comment: Finaly i find the reason why it return false,it is because of a textbox contain "required" in my HTML,Thanks

Comment: Wondering if any of the answers helped..!

Answer (score 2):

check this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/L222J/3/)

You need to submit your form. either your submit button should be inside your form or else you have to call form submit manually. The following

```
$('#validate_now').click(function(){
      $('#create_campaign_form').submit();
   });
```

enters your submit handler  and alerts 1, if form is valid.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a submit button in the form like

```
<form id="create_campaign_form">
    <input type="text" name="campaign_name" id="campaign_name" />
    <input type="submit" class="button" value="Submit" id="validate_now"/>
</form>
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/L222J/)

or manually call the submit method in the button click

```
<form id="create_campaign_form">
    <input type="text" name="campaign_name" id="campaign_name" />
</form>

<input type="button" class="button" value="Submit" id="validate_now"/>
```

then

```
$('#validate_now').click(function () {
    $("#create_campaign_form").submit()
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/L222J/5/)

Comment: I need to call valid() with a number of buttons

Comment: @shijin see the below answer(same as my second answer), it should work in that case

Comment: @shijin when you submit the form the submitHandler will be called only  if the form is valid

Comment: valid() not call submitHandler () ?

Comment: It works fine with @ArunPJohny's example http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/L222J/2/.But not working in my form.may the problem is retlated to plugin

Comment: @shijin it works because your submit button is inside the form, it triggers the form submit, `.valid` will only return the state of the form, it won't submit the form. as i said in my answer problem is that you are not submitting the form in your code.

Answer (score 1):

put your button html inside form tag

```
<form id="create_campaign_form">
  <input type="text" name="campaign_name" id="campaign_name" >
  <button id="validate_now" >OK</button>
</form>
```

By default, button with out any type is submit in html5.

Comment: actually,alert($('#create_campaign_form').valid()); alwaise return false;That is the problem

Comment: no..it will not return false if you type something in textbox & it will call submitHandler also. but if you are not entering anything in textbox & clicking on button then in that case it will return false.